# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found in IIS for Yii PHP

Tags: php, iis, yii

I have hosted YII framework php application in IIS 7.0. I can able to view the default page, but when I try to access the other pages I am getting the error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I know the runtime path is not  valid but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            1) Download Url Rewriting Extension from:
```

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

```
            2)Install It then goto IIS Manager-> click on your site-> In Feature View there will be a Url writng icon double click it-> Browse your .htaccess to enable your rules.

        3) if you have no .htaccess file create it and paste the following code in it...


         RewriteEngine on

            # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

            # otherwise forward it to index.php
            RewriteRule . index.php
    I hope this will work for......
```