# Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found IIS 10 in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, api, symfony, iis

I have an Api Rest Php in Symfony Framework v4, published in IIS 10, when I access a controller method I get the following message:

```
HTTP 404.0 Error - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, the name has been changed or is currently unavailable.
```

*Extensiones*:

[image]

Example:

> `http://localhost/master/public/api/v1/invoice/send?token=123456`

**.htaccess ---> /master/public/**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Ref : [HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found in IIS for Yii PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651887/http-error-404-0-not-found-in-iis-for-yii-php)

Any ideas, why can't I access the controller?
Thank you

Comment: Run the basic diagnostics and see what it says, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: Only one URL is not working? Or all URL is not working on the project?

Comment: @BhavinThummar all URL is not working on the project

Comment: @LexLi Is this an additional extension? I will follow the steps

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero can you try with this below urls 1) "http://localhost/master/api/v1/invoice/send?token=123456"
 2) "http://localhost/master/"

Let me know what the error will be show.

Comment: did you convert the .htaccess rewrite rule in web.config? you could refer this link to convert the .htaccess to iis web.config https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/23/converting-apache-htaccess-rules-to-iis-web-config-using-iis-manager-for-azure-websites/. select /master/public/ folder in iis and then follow this link steps. and it will create a web.config file in your /master/public/ folder.

Comment: realize several configurations and installations, and then IIS all fail, now I have had to reset it, very sad experience, I will continue when I have enough